# Помогите с сортировкой ASC с БД

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать чтобы сортировка цен начиналось с 1 а не с 0 когда выводишь с бд,У меня в бд значения 0, 2500, 0, 30 , 500, 1. Мне надо так чтобы от 1 до 2500, а не с двух  нулей

```html
$sorting = $_GET["sort"];

switch ($sorting)
{
        
        case 'price-asc' ;
        $sorting = 'targeting ASC';
        $sort_name = 'Дешевле';
        
        break;
        
        case 'price-desc';
        $sorting = 'targeting DESC';
        $sort_name = 'Дороже';
        break;
        
        case 'darom';
        $sorting = 'darom DESC';
        $sort_name = 'Даром';
        break;
        
        case 'obmen';
        $sorting = 'obmen DESC';
        $sort_name = 'Обмен';
        break;
        
        case 'new';
        $sorting = 'datatime DESC';
        $sort_name = 'Новинки';
        break;
        
    default:
        $sorting = 'products_id DESC';
        $sort_name = 'Нет сортировки!';
        break;
}
```

```html
<?php
            
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products ORDER BY $sorting",$connect);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                do{
                    
                    if  ($row["imagesad"] != "" && file_exists("ph_main/".$row["imagesad"]))
                    {
                        $img_path = 'ph_main/'.$row["imagesad"];
                        $max_width = 114; 
                        $max_height = 114; 
                        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_path); 
                        $ratioh = $max_height/$height; 
                        $ratiow = $max_width/$width; 
                        $ratio = min($ratioh, $ratiow); 
                        $width = intval($ratio*$width); 
                        $height = intval($ratio*$height);    
                    }else
                    {
                        $img_path = "images/no-image.png";
                        $width = 110;
                        $height = 200;
                    }
                    
                                     echo '
                        <li>
                        <div class="block-images-grid">
                        <img src="'.$img_path.'" width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'">
                        </div>
                        <p class="style-title-grid"><a href="">'.$row["title"].'</a></p>
                        <ul class="reviews-and-counts-grid">
                        <li><img src="images/eye-icon.png"><p>0</p></li>
                        <li><img src="images/comment-icon.png"><p>0</p></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="style-price-grid"><strong>'.(!empty($row["darom"]) ? $row["darom"] : (!empty($row["obmen"]) ? $row["obmen"] : $row["targeting"])).'</strong></p>
                        <div class="mini-features">
                        <p>Город:'.$row["gorod"].'</p>
                        <p id="datatime">Дата:'.$row["datatime"].'</p>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    ';
                }
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
            }
                
                
            ?>
```

Comment: А записи с нулями где в выборке должны быть - в конце ? Или может их вообще быть не должно и стоило в `where price>0` отфильтровать

Comment: ...и эти товары действительно бесплатны, или их цены просто нет? Потому что в последнем случае там `NULL` должен бы быть... .-.

Comment: у них цены просто нет а  в бд заносится значение 0, вот мне надо чтобы сортировка не затрагивала товар с значением 0

Comment: Подскажет кто как сделать то?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, какой результат вы хотите получить. Если необходимо, чтобы нули были в конце выборки, то можно использовать

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY targeting = 0;
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы выборка совсем не имела данных с ценой 0, то необходимо поставить условие WHERE

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE targering > 0 ORDER BY targering ASC;
```

Comment: Я вот в инете тоже подобное нашел, мне вот 2 вариант нужен. Не могли бы подсказать куда его писать? Прошу прощения за такой вопрос, сам недавно начал изучать просто)

Comment: Найдите в коде исходный запрос или момент его формирования и подставьте туда в условие (или добавьте условие, если его нет) targering > 0. Я даже имея сверхспособности, не смогу сказать куда в вашем коде его вставлять, без наличия кода :)

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE targeting > 0 ORDER BY $sorting",$connect) вот код который подействовал, но появилось одно но. Пропала сортировка obmen и darom, как можно это исправить ребят?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться условной сортировкой, пустив сначала значения больше 0, а потом те, которые принимают значение 0

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  IF(targering > 0, 0, 1),
  targering;
```